# Items in recyclerview are not shown unless declaring adapter again in the observer methode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I'm having a problem with my adapter/recyclerview. I want the user to see an overview of appointments like this:[image]

But i can only do this be setting the adapter for the recylerview in the observe method.
This the code:

```
        val adapter = CalendarAdapter()

        binding.appointmentList.adapter = adapter

        calendarDataViewModel?.appointments?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.data = it
                binding.appointmentList.adapter = adapter
            }
        })
```

Like you see, if I set the adapter again inside the observe method, the items will be shown, but if I don't do that, nothing will be shown and it will just be an empty screen.

I also tried the following code, but this also doesnt work:

```
val adapter = CalendarAdapter()

binding.appointmentList.adapter = adapter

calendarDataViewModel?.appointments?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    it?.let {
            adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })
```

I can't seem to figure out why this isnt working.
Appointments is of the type LiveData<List>

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is my CalendarAdapter:

```
class CalendarAdapter : ListAdapter<CalendarData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(AppointmentDiffCallback()) {
    var data = listOf<CalendarData>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return AppointmentViewHolder(CalendarItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val appointment = data[position]
        (holder as AppointmentViewHolder).bind(appointment)
    }
}

private class AppointmentDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CalendarData>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CalendarData, newItem: CalendarData): Boolean {
        return oldItem.appointmentId == newItem.appointmentId
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CalendarData, newItem: CalendarData): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to override the `getItemCount` method. In your case, `data.size` returns 0 due to which the items are never shown.

Also, you do not need to keep track of your items, `ListAdapter` abstract class already does that. You can get your Item using `getItem(Int)` method. Your adapter should be something like so:

```kotlin
class CalendarAdapter : ListAdapter<CalendarData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(AppointmentDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return AppointmentViewHolder(CalendarItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val appointment = getItem(position)
        (holder as AppointmentViewHolder).bind(appointment)
    }
}
```

Then in your observer you can the `submitList` method like in your second code block in the question.